# How can I achieve a many-to-many (multiple teams can access the same document) firestore structure

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In my firestore, I have multiple "teams" with multiple users. Currently, every document has a team assigned to it in the "team" field and I have security rules that check wether the user's team (saved as a custom claim) is the same as the team of the document. Because [firestore security rules aren't filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters), I have to filter for the team with every query and make composite indexes if I want an array-contains or range filter on another field. Example current query (searchTerms as an example of a second field being queried):

```
firebase.firestore().collection("docs").where("team", "==", token.claims.team).where("searchTerms", "array-contains", searchTerm.toUpperCase());
```

Now I want to allow multiple teams access to the same document. I had the idea to use an array-contains, but this would disallow me from using another array-contains in the same query:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("docs").where("teams", "array-contains", token.claims.team).where("searchTerms", "array-contains", searchTerm.toUpperCase());
```

How can I structure my database/queries to achieve multiple groups per document and array-contains and range filters on other fields?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an array of authorised teams you could have, for each team, a field with the name of the team and a value set to `true` (or whatever else actually).

Then your query will be as follows:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("docs").where(token.claims.team, "==", true).where("searchTerms", "array-contains", searchTerm.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: I've considered this, but as far as I understand it would require me to make an index per team, which is not feasible.

Comment: With the **exact** query in my answer you don’t need a composite index

Comment: ah, I didn't know that array-contains can be used without the composite index requirement. Do you know of a way though to get it with a range/unequal check, so if the second query was searchTerms >= ...?

Comment: Adding an inequality clause will need a composite index indeed. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview). Depending on the size of the result you may sort them in the front-end.

Comment: Hey @bcye did you see my last comment? Do you need more help on this subject?

Comment: Hi yes, thank you for that. I was looking to maintain all query capabilities (as creating an index per team is not really an option as its limiting the number of teams), but it seems to be impossible. I was rather originally trying to see if there was a way to structure the database so that I wouldn't need to create composite indexes/work around this problem, as I couldn't find a way with having a teams field.

Comment: Yes Firestore comes with great advantages (speed and scalability, among many others) but also with limitations. It’s up to you to find the database (SQL or NoSQL) that corresponds to your needs